# Airdots distorted audio while calling

Tags: audio

I have a **Xiaomi Redmi Note 6 pro** and a pair of **black Xiaomi AirDots** but every time I call and play music together, the music is as distorted as the call itself like the music's coming from the caller.

How can I undistort the audio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Bluetooth has many *profiles*, ie. modes that have different capabilities. When you're just playing music, the phone is using A2DP profile which is optimized for unidirectional high-quality sound. When you're calling someone, the phone switches to HSP profile, which offers bidirectional sound - but allocating some of the bandwidth for microphone reduces bandwidth available for incoming audio, degrading quality. You can't have both because there's not enough bandwidth.